# Filter with multivalue columns in Redshift/SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have a table with news articles. These news articles have many columns that describe title, picture and so on. Some of the columns can have multiple values, e.g. category can be set to both "sports" and "hockey".

Lets say I have this table:

```
articlekey | category
---------------------
article1   | sports, hockey
```

The actual table contains a lot of articles and all the articles are present only once. What I try to achieve is to filter on this table, on both values of category. To be able to do that, I have split them into to rows and generated a filter-table like this:

```
articlekey | category
---------------------
article1   | sports
article1   | hockey
```

(btw. we use Tableau as visualization/BI-tool, and that is where I filter)

When I left join these to tables and filter (include) only on "hockey", I will get the correct result, since article1 only have one row with category set to "hockey".

```
articlekey | category         | category-filter
-----------------------------------------------
article1   | sports, hockey   | sports          <-- this will be excluded
article1   | sports, hockey   | hockey          <-- this is included
```

But if I try to exclude "hockey", the article will show up with category set to "sports", since it persists in the result with category "sports". The result I want it to exclude the article entirely.

```
articlekey | category         | category-filter
-----------------------------------------------
article1   | sports, hockey   | sports          <-- this is included, but should also be gone
article1   | sports, hockey   | hockey          <-- this will be excluded
```

If possible, how should I work with data like this, when I have multiple values per column and need to filter (include and exclude) so that I only have one row per article left.

Comment: I am using Redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. If you have 'normalized' data structure for the categories, i.e. no multiple values in category field (like in your 'filter-table'):**

I think the preferred way to solve this is to substitute 1 for 'hockey', 0 for everything else then sum up these numbers on groups by articlekey. Articlekeys with sum of 0 are the articles without 'hockey' category.

So this is the query for articles having NO 'hockey' category:

```
select articlekey
from articles 
group by articlekey 
having sum(case when category = 'hockey' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You can generalize this: for example if you need articles with NEITHER 'hockey' NOR 'sports' but having BOTH 'soccer' AND 'boxing' categories:

```
select articlekey
from articles 
group by articlekey 
having sum(
  case when category = 'hockey' then 1
       when category = 'sports' then 1
       else 0 
  end
) = 0
and sum(
  case when category = 'soccer' then 1
       when category = 'boxing' then 1
       else 0 
  end
) = 2;
```

But you can also
1. filter on category (hockey)
2. group by on articleKey
3. count matches
4. left join

So this is another solution:

```
select * from articles left join (
  select articlekey, count(articlekey) as countOfHockey 
  from articles where category = 'hockey' group by articlekey
) hhh on articles.articlekey=hhh.articlekey where countOfHockey is null;
```

Sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/27ae1/33

**II. If you have de-normalized category fields, i.e. category lists as comma separated lists of values (like in your original table), you can utilize SQL like %% operator on them and write queries like these:**

```
create table if not exists articles(articlekey varchar, category varchar);
insert into articles values('article1', 'sports, hockey');
insert into articles values('article2', 'sports');
insert into articles values('article3', 'soccer, boxing, sprint');
insert into articles values('article4', 'soccer, sprint');

select * from articles where ', '||category||',' not like '%, hockey,%';
```

You can generalize this also, if you need articles with NEITHER 'hockey' NOR 'sports' but having BOTH 'soccer' AND 'boxing' categories:

```
select * from articles where 
', '||category||',' not like '%, hockey,%' and
', '||category||',' not like '%, sports,%' and
', '||category||',' like '%, soccer,%' and
', '||category||',' like '%, boxing,%';
```

Note however, that this approach is usually not the preferred way to handle data in a relational database.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. I'll look into this.

Comment: Thank you @riskop. This is very helpful :)